# Split array object by string by @ sign

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

i have the flowing array object

```
let old_array = {
 "valone":  "facebook",
 "notification": "new message! @user1@example.com @user2@example.com"
}
```

i want break get the all users with @ sign into new array like bellow

```
let new_array = {"user1@example.com", "user2@example.com"}
```

any idea how to do this i have user array split im only able to get email with @ sign.

```
let new_array = old_array .split("@");
```

Comment: your *array* is an object.

Comment: `old_array` and `new_array` are **not**  Array objects.

Comment: `split` is a string method.

Comment: You have many issues with the information in your post, most important is that you are confusing a JavaScript array and a JavaScript object.  Technically speaking, JS 'arrays' are a type of object, however, in the JS realm, we need to be specific and use correct terminolgy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```js
let old_array = {
 "valone":  "facebook",
 "notification": "new message! @user1@example.com @user2@example.com"
}

const result =  old_array.notification.match(/(?<=@)(\w*@\w*.\w*)/g);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: run code snippet says "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the string inside `old_array`. Try this:

```js
let old_array = {
  "valone":  "facebook",
  "notification": "new message! @user1@example.com @user2@example.com"
}
    
let notification = old_array["notification"]; //Get notification-property
    
let email_string = notification.substring(notification.indexOf("@")).trim(); //Get rid of the message
    
let email_array = email_string.split(" "); //Split by " " to get the different emails
    
console.log(email_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match the email by searching for `@` following by non white space.

```js
var string = 'new message! @user1@example.com @user2@example.com',
    emails = string.match(/@\S+/g);

console.log(emails);
```